# how to get info from "JBUFFER_TRACE()" in kernel

Tags: kernel, journal

all. From the jbd2(journal block device2) code in linux kernel, i see the “JBUFFER_TRACE()” trace log, such as "JBUFFER_TRACE(jh, "on shadow: sleep");".

While i want to know how to print the info in user space. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the macro `JBUFFER_TRACE` [does nothing](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/jbd2.h#L1514) within the kernel.You may edit this header file and define the macro as you want. E.g., with use of `printk`.

Comment: Good idea! I can have try. Thanks!